# VPN on AWS doesn't work after a ISP offer change

Tags: networking, vpn, openvpn, ipv6, amazon-web-services

I've set up a VPN connection to my AWS server using [this guide](https://www.comparitech.com/blog/vpn-privacy/how-to-make-your-own-free-vpn-using-amazon-web-services/) and it has been working fine until my ISP changed my offer. They doubled my internet speed, replaced my router and made me use ipv6 by default if that's relevant.

OpenVPN connects fine, but Windows shows that there is no internet connection. The sites are trying to load, but usually fail. Sometimes I manage to display a google home page after waiting 30 seconds or so. And of course my internet without trying to use VPN works perfectly fine.

Here is the screen from [trace route](https://i.stack.imgur.com/75UUQ.png) and [OpenVPN log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JXZ97.png).

I also tried disabling ipv6 protocol on both networks (my normal and vpn's one), [screen here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VEBU1.png).

I would appreciate any help, thanks.

Comment: did you re-install the VPN connection?

Comment: I didn't reinstall every package like openvpn or easy-rsa, but I remade all certificates and configs. I might repeat the whole process from scratch, but that will be not earlier than in 14 hours, because I have no time now.

Comment: What does your routing table show ?

Comment: $ route -> https://imgur.com/mK99T6S.png

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Issue solved.

My new router was using IPv6 configuration, which caused VPN to not work. I had to contact my ISP to change it to IPv4 and everything went back to normal.

Comment: Disabling IPv6 is at best a temporary workaround while you sort out the real problem. It's the 21st century now and IPv6 is becoming increasingly necessary to reach various parts of the world, especially as IPv4 becomes less and less reliable. It will soon be impossible to communicate with many people without it - including yourself!